# Passing row id of a list to another activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two activity. When the user clicks on the medicine name on the list, it will go to second activity and display the details of the medicine. 
 For the first activity, below is my code:

```
public class MedicineView extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medicine_view);
    ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    // view data

    try{
        String query = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_MEDICINE;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int getIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MED_ID);
            int getNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MED_NAME);
            int getDosageIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DOSAGE);
            int getFrequencyIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FREQUENCY);

            if(c.isFirst())
            {
                do{
                    idList.add(c.getLong(getIndex));
                    result.add(c.getString(getNameIndex)+" | " + c.getString(getDosageIndex)
                            +" | " + c.getString(getFrequencyIndex)+"\n" );
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        c.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e){  
    }

    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onClickHome(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuUtama.class));
}

public void onClickAdd(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicineAdd.class));
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MedicineDetail.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
} // end class
```

and this is my second activity

```
public class MedicineDetail extends Activity 
 {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Button btnEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.medicine_detail);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final int id = i.getIntExtra("int", -1);
    //int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 2);

    btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_MEDICINE + " WHERE id = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    try{
        if( cursor != null ){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   idList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(6));
               } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){  
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    TextView StartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    TextView EndDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TextView MedName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TextView Dosage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TextView Frequency =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView Instruction =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    StartDate.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    EndDate.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    MedName.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    Dosage.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    Frequency.setText(cursor.getString(5));
    Instruction.setText(cursor.getString(6));
    cursor.close();

}

public void onClickHome(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicineView.class));
}

} // end class
```

this is my logcat

```
03-05 08:55:08.985: W/Bundle(2186): Key ID expected Integer but value was a    java.lang.Long.  The default value -1 was returned.
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:933)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(Intent.java:3683)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at com.android.MyDoc.MedicineDetail.onCreate(MedicineDetail.java:32)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 08:55:09.005: W/Bundle(2186):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 08:55:09.053: D/AndroidRuntime(2186): Shutting down VM
03-05 08:55:09.053: W/dalvikvm(2186): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.MyDoc/com.android.MyDoc.MedicineDetail}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:434)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at com.android.MyDoc.MedicineDetail.onCreate(MedicineDetail.java:70)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-05 08:55:09.093: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: In your table `TABLE_MEDICINE`, are you sure there are 7 columns?

Comment: yup, med_id, startdate, enddate, med_name, dosage, frequency and instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** : you are getting the long value but id returns  int so it throws classcast exception

instead of this

```
idList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
```

use this

```
 idList.add(cursor.getInt(0));
```

---

Your id is different from the rowid in the table.. Don't mess up with them, You are sending id of the position in your list.
So what you need to do is

Create a Hashmap to map ids with data globally

```
Hashmap Idshash=new Hashmap();
```

Add values to the hasmap while inserting to results list

```
long id=c.getLong(getIndex);
String item=c.getString(getNameIndex)+" | " + c.getString(getDosageIndex)
                            +" | " + c.getString(getFrequencyIndex);
   idList.add(id);
Idshash.put(item,id);
  result.add(item);
```

And in onitemclick listener do like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item=((TextView)v).getText();
    long selectedid=Idshash.get(item);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MedicineDetail.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("ID", selectedid);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: the hashmap is inside the first or second actvity?

Comment: ya, it think the id is different coz when i printout the id form the intent, different from the second page

Comment: and in the dbhelper, should i make a method for getdata based on ID?

Comment: i try already, when i change from getLong to getInt, the add got error, the method add(int,Long) in the type arrayList(Long) is not applicable to the arguments int

Comment: then i change private ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); but still got CursorIndexOutOfBound

Answer (score 1):

in the second activity there is a problem

```
in the first activity 



 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MedicineDetail.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("ID", position);
    startActivity(myIntent);



final int id = i.getIntExtra("int", -1); should be

final int id = i.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the caller activity you have: `myIntent.putExtra("ID", id);`

While in the opened activity instead of

```
i.getIntExtra("int", -1);
```

it should be

```
i.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
```

Notice that the name of the extra should be the same when you try to get it from the intent.

Comment: actually at first i don't know what to put inside at the -1.. when i put 1 it done but all item i click will display the same which is with the index 1

Comment: after you call `id = i.getIntExtra("ID", -1);` is `id != -1` ?

Comment: i think the id start from 1 when i test it, but i want the id is flexible so the data display will based on the id

Comment: Try to print in logcat the value of the `id` when you send it and when you receive it to see if it's the same. Also check this id exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

in first actvity change the `id` to `position`. That's all.

```
 myIntent.putExtra("ID", position);
```

and in second

```
getIntExtra("ID", -1);
```

or

```
getExtra("ID", -1);
```